# Counting records under multiple criteria in DAX

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 tables.

A. Customer table.
Key column include 1. Customer ID (primary key) and 2. First Date purchase (in Date field) and 3. First purchase Date Year & Month (in text, like Jul 01).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMszs.png)

B. Sales table.
Key column include 1. Customer ID (foreign key) and 2. Sales order date (in Date field).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLGiu.png)

Both tables was in 1-many relationship. I want to find out how many customer return within 60 days since their first purchase, group by First purchase Date Year & Month. For example,

- Jul-01 will have 2 return customer who return within 60 days since first purchase
- Aug-01 had no within 60 day return customer
- Sep-01 had 1 within 60 days return customer

I will then perform calculation in pivot table for % of return customer per first purchase month, like below.

My desire result was a pivot table in below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFOIO.png)

### I can do it by adding a calculated column in Customer table with below dax as filter to either 1 (the customer had reorder within 60days) or 0, then calculate at pivot table field:

### IF(CALCULATE(COUNT(Sales[ProductKey]),FILTER(Sales,Sales[OrderDate]>Customers[DateFirstPurchase] && Sales[OrderDate] - Customers[DateFirstPurchase] <=60 && Sales[CustomerKey] = Customers[CustomerKey]))>0,1,0)

But as Sales had quite a large volumn, and it's not a best practice to use Filter in this case. Therefore, can this be achieve by either:

1. Not using Filter function in calculated column ? i.e. check matching record from Customer table ? or other ways ? Or, ideally
2. Use Dax instead of adding calculated column.

It's highly appreciated for yours' help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a relationship in a model then you don't need a Sales[CustomerKey] = Customers[CustomerKey]; Try to use this calculation (not tested).

```
MeasureToCount = CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS (
        CALCULATETABLE (
             VALUES(Sales[CustomerKey]),
            FILTER (
                Sales,
                 Sales[SalesOrderDate]  > RELATED(Customer[FirstPurchase])
                    &&  (Sales[SalesOrderDate])  <= ( RELATED(Customer[FirstPurchase]) + 60 )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Now if you add "Year & Month" to Table visualization with measure, that should work.

Output from powerbi Desktop:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Msta42a, thanks for the measure. There's no column (like Sales(OrderDate)) I can choose after Related function. But there's active relationship between both tables. Any clues ?

Comment: In your post: "Table B. Sales table. Key column include 1. Customer ID (foreign key) and 2. Sales order date (in Date field). "; Then you have SalesOrderDate or not? Your relationship is based on CustomerID?

Comment: Hi Msta42a, yes, Sales table have SalesOrderDate and the relationship (1 (customer) to many (Sales)) is based on Customer ID. I perform it via Power pivot.

Comment: Each customer had different sales, thus different sales order date. But each customer had only 1 first purchase date.

Comment: Edit your post and add in plain text some example of your data <you can post dummy data>; And add your desired output.

Comment: Hi msta42a, add data and desired outcome for your further reference. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi msta42a, thanks for your help, the measure works and I confirm  your answer. While i can see the logic of the your answer was quite similar to mine, i.e. to filter the sales table. It of course works, but the actual Sales table have quite a huge volume, may I ask if I can have the same result by filter customer table ?

Comment: You can try:  CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS (
        CALCULATETABLE (
             VALUES(Customer[CustomerKey]),
            FILTER (
                Sales,
                RELATED( Sales[SalesOrderDate] ) > (Customer[FirstPurchase])
                    && RELATED (Sales[SalesOrderDate])  <= ( (Customer[FirstPurchase]) + 60 )
            )
        )
    )
)

Comment: Hi msta42a, thanks for the suggestion. The intellisense engine shown no column field after RELATED function. Furthermore, it seems the dax still filtering Sales table (please correct me if I'm wrong ^^).

Comment: Its hard to say. Did you change Table in FILTER? If you want to know what exactly is going on, then use DaxStudio with ServerTiming feature (really good tool for performance optimization <how the current measure perform and how after change>. For dax is important the order of filter condition (if first return FALSE then second isn't execute).